# How to import classes in subfolders

Tags: python, python-3.x

On Python 3.6

I want to organize my classes in folders.

ClassX in folder Classes

Subclass_of_ClassX in a subfolder

```
MyPackage
    -__init__.py
    -someCode.py
    -folder Classes
        -__init__.py
        -ClassX.py
        -Subfolder SubClasses
            -__init__.py
            -Subclass_of_ClassX.py
```

Subclass_of_ClassX overriddes elements (functions and variables) from ClassX

The question is: if I import ClassX on any project, and I get any instance of Subclass_of_ClassX, and I want to use any overriden function, do I need to explicitly import the subclass?

Or can I just import ClassX and abstract from any inherited class, using any subclass instance as if it were ClassX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get an instance of `Subclass_of_ClassX` from somewhere, you don't need to additionally import the class at all. Importing a class just makes the name available in your current scope (module).

You only need to import the class or subclass when you need to...

- create a new instance
- write a subclass
- use it otherwise like in `isinstance(obj, ClassX)`

Answer (score 0):

If you got instance of class - you already don't need to import anything, because it was imported in some other place already.

Comment: by "instance of class", you also mean any subclass instance?

Comment: Yeah, I am talking about subclass - instances already have link to their class, so you can't create instance without having class imported somewhere.

You can even get Subclass itself, without importing it, by `instance.__class__`

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is not the Pythonic way to structure packages.

You'll end up with having to do

```
from mypackage.Classes.ClassX import ClassX
```

when you could do with

```
from mypackage.class_x import ClassX
```

If your package is, uh, for the sake of example, a zoo where you have animals and foods, I would suggest putting the animals in one package and their foods in another.

- `myzoo/__init__.py` (empty)
- `myzoo/animals/__init__.py` (empty)
- `myzoo/animals/base.py` (containing your `Animal` base class)
- `myzoo/animals/cats.py` (containing `Lion` and `Tiger`, for instance)
- `myzoo/foods/__init__.py` (empty)
- `myzoo/foods/base.py` (containing your `Food` base class)
- `myzoo/foods/kibbles.py` (containing kibbles for the cats, not that they'll like them)

(You could also have one file per animal/food, and probably should if you anticipate them growing large.)